# iOS webView not fitting the content inside screen width?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

I know this is a quite a common question , though I can't figure out the solution to this issue.

I am loading a url in a webView.I want the web page to fit inside the bounds of the iPhone screen.So I did  `webView.scalesPageToFit = YES`  for my webView.However the loaded page still loads like a zoomed in view .

This is my webView delegate method.Also I am using iOS 8 , if that makes any difference.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView //executes 
{
   NSLog(@"webViewDidFinishLoad");
   self.webView.scalesPageToFit =YES;
   self.webView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit; //have set these properties in storyboard also

}
```

Comment: Did you set the viewport in your HTML ?

Comment: I just have a string for URL

Comment: Then you have to set the meta viewport

Comment: in delegate method itself?

Comment: Read "meta viewport" documentation. Set it in HTML's `<head>`